# Knowing what exogenous variable cause quasi-separation

Tags: logistic, python, statsmodels, separation

I'm trying to build a classifier using a logistic regression and statsmodel is telling me that there is an issue of quasi-separation.

Well this isn't an issue! This is exactly what i'm trying to do: predicting the Endogenous Variable using the Exogenous Variable!

The real problem is that i can't find the output telling me what variable cause it and what are the associated values. Can anyone hint me where to find that?

Here is my error message

> Possibly complete quasi-separation: A fraction 0.62 of observations can be
>   perfectly predicted. This might indicate that there is complete
>   quasi-separation. In this case some parameters will not be identified.

I'm using Python 3.4 and statsmodel 0.6.1

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/137547/17230. And it's "quasi-complete separation".

Comment: I uploaded my Error Message. I understand that in the post you linked that they are talking about collinearity between exogenous variables. But I wouldn't think i have the problem...

Comment: Is this raising an exception or just print a warning? If you have the results, then I think there should be some parameters with large values or very large standard errors. If that's the case, then these parameters would not be identified because of quasi-complete separation.

Comment: I wasn't linking to the question, but to my answer, which references a linear programming algorithm to identify which predictors cause separation.